# How to use an actionresult to return both a view and a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I use use an actionResult  to return both a view and a partial view.  Actually in case of an ajax request it should send a partial view else it should send a view.

```
   public ActionResult Test(string Name ="", DateTime? Date= null, string sex="" )
         {            
             myModel model = new myModel(Name, Date, Sex);
             if(IsAjaxRequest)
                 return PartialView("partialView", model)
             else
                 return View(model);
         }
```

Comment: And how would the response look like? How do you intend to invoke this action and most importantly consume the response?

Comment: No idea at all, only enquiring if that`s possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView("_Article", model);

return View(model);
```